# Term for radius and gradient of spacetime distortion?

Tags: general-relativity

A black hole would distort spacetime time to a greater degree than planet Earth. That is, both the radius and the gradient of the distortion are greater.

Is there a term that combines "greater radius" and "greater gradient" into one?

In layman terms, a black hole distorts spacetime more "aggressively" than planet Earth.

Comment: Stellar-mass black holes have radii that are much *smaller* than Earth.

Comment: I didn’t know that. Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Spacetime distortion is measured by the [Riemann curvature tensor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_curvature_tensor) $R_{\mu\nu\lambda\kappa}$. This tensor has 256 components, but various symmetries reduce the number of independent components to 20. So, in general, it takes 20 numbers at each point in spacetime to fully describe how spacetime is distorted.

The simplest way to compare the spacetime curvature of a Schwarzschild black hole versus that of the Earth is to consider a curvature invariant like the [Kretschmann scalar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kretschmann_scalar). This is just a single number, and it is much larger at the event horizon of a stellar-mass black hole than it is at the surface of the Earth.